Using terraform, how to configure an eventbridge target for Systems Manager Run Command with target input of "Constant"
I am unable to find terraform to support filling out the details in the photo to configure parameters for the “Configure target input” type of “Constant.”
My terraform code currently looks something like the below, but this code will not fill in those same sections. From the event bridge target tab everything seems to be correct, but when I click to edit to check if it was filled out, it’s all blank and won’t work when triggered and I’m not receiving any errors.
I have tried input_transformer, but that is a drop down option for the "Configure target input" and is not correct, I've tried the input_paths, but nothing seems to work. The below is the baseline that I have come back to as it fills out everything and looks right at least from the target tab view, but that's it. My expectation is when I click to view the target the parameters for sourceType, sourceInfo, and commandline are filled in.
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "test" {
  target_id = "test"
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console.name
  arn       = “arn:<region>:ssm:::document/AWS-RunRemoteScript” 
  Role_arn = aws_iam_role.my_role.arn

  run_command_targets {
    key    = "tag:Name"
    values = ["FooBar"]
  }

  Inputs =  {
    sourceType= “S3”,
    soureInfo = “[<url path to my bucket/file>]”,
    commandLine = “powershell file.ps1”
  }
}

event-bridge-target-aws-console
